# Returning postcodes (varchars) with only one numeric character in them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been asked to run a query to return a list of UK post codes from a table full of filters for email reports which only have 1 number at the end. The problem is that UK post codes are of variable length; some are structured 'AA#' or 'AA##' and some are structured 'A#' or 'A##'. I only want those that are either 'AA#' or 'A#'.

I tried running the below SQL, using length and (attempting to) use regex to filter out all results which didn't match what I wanted, but I'm very new to using ranges and it hasn't worked.

```
SELECT PostCode
FROM ReportFilterTable RFT
WHERE RFT.FilterType = 'Postcode' 
AND LEN(RFT.Postcode) < 4 
AND RFT.PostCode LIKE '%[0-9]'
```

I think the way I'm approaching this is flawed, but I'm clueless as to a better way. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Since I helpfully didn't include any example data originally, I've now done so below.

This is a sample of the kind of values in the column I'm returning, with examples of what I need to return and what I don't.

- B1   -- Should be returned
- B10  -- Should not be returned
- B2   -- Should be returned
- B20  -- Should not be returned
- B3   -- Should be returned
- B30  -- Should not be returned
- SE1  -- Should be returned
- SE10 -- Should not be returned

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Do you mean one number, or one digit?

Comment: Ah, apologies, it's my first question! I'll update the tags and data now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter for one or two letters (and omit the length check, since it's implicit in the LIKE):

```
WHERE RFT.FilterType = 'Postcode' AND
      (RFT.PostCode LIKE '[A-Z][0-9]' OR RFT.PostCode LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]')
```

Comment: This did it. Results returned are all either in 'AA#' or A#' format.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you are getting values with multiple digits *and* you are using SQL Server (as suggested by the syntax), then you can do:

```
WHERE RFT.FilterType = 'Postcode' AND
      LEN(RFT.Postcode) < 4 AND
      (RFT.PostCode LIKE '%[0-9]' AND RFT.PostCode NOT LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]')
```

Or, if you know there are at least two characters, you could use:

```
WHERE RFT.FilterType = 'Postcode' AND
      LEN(RFT.Postcode) < 4 AND
      RFT.PostCode LIKE '%[^0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-digit followed by 1 digit  `... LIKE '%[^0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: Problem is is that it's not necessarily a single non-numeric character followed by a numeric one.

Comment: This is really something + non-digit + digit. So it matches AA1 and A1. And  1A1 too.